# Node interpreter KO in cygwin?

Tags: windows, node.js, cygwin

Node works fine, but node interpreter launches only in Windows command line tool (or "PowerShell"), not in Cygwin (cygwin.bat or with putty through an SSH connection).

I have no error, the interpreter just leaves quietly, with a return code of 0.

I am using Windows 8 / 64bits and I installed latest node.js MSI.

Would anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Hum no, now I just use power shell to run the interpreter on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is no longer supported for node.js. Check [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) .The latest version that compiles on Cygwin is 0.4.12.

Besides node.js is supported natively in Windows. Don't use node.js on Cygwin.

Comment: My question is not related to compilation of node.js in cygwin, as I mentioned in my question I am using the MSI install. I am asking about node's interpreter.

Comment: It is not just related to complation. Node.js has dropped support entirely for Cygwin since then. You cant run it from Cygwin.